# Aligning text in java JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, jlabel

I am a new student of java.This is a college project, a math test in a gui.
I have problems with alignment.

I would like to do this in my gui when I run the program

```
                        Math Test - 10 exercises  (this in the middle)
                           about 2 spaces here

1. How much is one added to one?  ( this is an example. the math problems are going to be word problems with several sentences.)

a space here

Your answer, please.   here goes a JTextField (4)


about 2 spaces here

2.  here goes exercise number 2 


etc. etc.
```

What do you think is better for the math word problems JLabel or JTextArea?

here I imported swing and awt

```
public class MathTest extends JPanel 
{
    public JTextField stu;

    public MathTest() {
         JLabel m=new JLabel ();
         m.setText ("Math Test - 10 exercises");
         add(m);

         JLabel exone= JLabel();
         exone.setText("1. how much is one added to one?");
         add(exone);

         JLabel y= new JLabel();
         y.setText ("Your answer, please.");
         add(y);

         stu= JTextField (4); 
         add(stu);       
    }
}
```

The programs works but I cannot align the labels and the JTextfield.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll want to look into using a [`LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). My personal recommendation is the very flexible [`MigLayout`](http://www.miglayout.com/). It takes a little while to learn, but is well worth it.

Comment: It might help to take a screenshot of what it looks like now and then draw a picture of what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
setSize(x,y);
```

dimension according to your choice 
or simply use Net bean editor that can provide facility for drag and drop

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want learn any layout manager. Use absolute layout for a Jpanel.
Then you can place your label wherever you want.

```
Jpanel.setLayout(null);
JLabel lb=new JLabel("hi");
lb.setBounds(x,y,width,height);
```